# Qt phonon media object error

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, phonon

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <Phonon/MediaSource>
#include <QUrl>
#include <Phonon/MediaObject>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QUrl url("http://www.example.com/music.ogg");
    Phonon::MediaObject *wow =
             Phonon::createPlayer(Phonon::NoCategory,
                                  Phonon::MediaSource(url));
         wow->play();

   }
```

This code won't play the file, and I'm getting this error:

> :: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Can anyone help me get the file to play when I click the button?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a linker error in your code, so it seems like the code isn't even generating a valid executable.  Can you post more about the error you're getting?  Right now all I can say is that your program won't link.

Comment: Hi, thats the only error I get , when I click build. -- Thanks

Comment: Can you put more data of this error? Whats above the :: error: collect2...

Comment: na Go to compile output . There you can get the original and exact errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that there are one or more functions declared in the header file but their bodies haven't been built yet.

for example:

```
//headerfile
class MyClass
{
    public: MyClass();
    private: void function1();
             void function2();
};

//source file
MyClass::MyClass(){}
void MyClass::function1(){ /*do something*/ }
//here function2 is missing.
```

So, please check that all the functions in the whole project have their bodies.

For a basic phonon media player,

```
#ifndef MYVIDEOPLAYER_H
#define MYVIDEOPLAYER_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <Phonon/VideoPlayer>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class MyVideoPlayer : public QWidget
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
      explicit MyVideoPlayer(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
      Phonon::VideoPlayer *videoPlayer;
      QPushButton *btnButton;
      QVBoxLayout layout;

private slots:
      void onPlay();
};
#endif // MYVIDEOPLAYER_H

#include "myvideoplayer.h"

MyVideoPlayer::MyVideoPlayer(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    videoPlayer=new Phonon::VideoPlayer(Phonon::VideoCategory,this);
    btnButton=new QPushButton("Play",this);

    layout.addWidget(btnButton);
    layout.addWidget(videoPlayer);

    setLayout(&layout);

    connect(btnButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(onPlay()));
}

void MyVideoPlayer::onPlay()
{
    videoPlayer->load(Phonon::MediaSource("movie.mp4"));
    videoPlayer->play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As templatetypedef commented, it sounds like a linker error.  Ensure that you have added all of the necessary libraries to the .pro file.  For example, you need to link against Phonon, so your .pro file must contain

```
QT += phonon
```